# Time out on saving new registers into Elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch cluster with 3 nodes (1 raw and 2 data), and multiple Node.js workers wrinting into this cluster (via the raw node), using the [elasticsearch module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch).

I have lost almost half of the writing operations getting timeout, and I don’t know what’s going on. I just suspect it’s a concurrency issue.

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Did you check the nodes ElasticSearch logfiles, are there any clues in it? Can you expand on the writes you make? Are you using batches? How much documents/second are you indexing from your workers? Do you have enough CPU for ES?

Comment: @mark The log has no clues, just trivial messages, everything looks fine. The write is batch of 16 documents. I have about 300 documents/second. The CPU usage of each node oscillates between 8% and 16%. The memory usage is about 27%.